# Geodesics of a Submanifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geodesic

How can one prove that every geodesics of a submanifold M are geodesics on the "bigger" manifold N? Intuitively it makes alot of sense but i can't work with the "mathematical tools" that i have.

My tools:

i) I know that the Levi-Civita connection will satisfy: $$\nabla^M_XY=(\nabla_\overline{X}^N\overline{Y})^T$$
Where $\overline{X},\overline{Y}\in\mathcal{X}(N)$  are smooth local extensions of $X, Y ∈ \mathcal{X} (M)$ (we assume that they exist), and $(\cdot)^T$ denotes the orthogonal projection onto the respective tangent space of M.

ii) We call M totally geodesic if:

$$\nabla^M_XY=\nabla_\overline{X}^N\overline{Y}$$

The problem is: Prove that each geodesic of M is also one of N.

Comment: Take a parallel $l$ on a 2-dimensional sphere $S$ which is *not* the equator. If what you are saying was true, $l$ would itself be geodesic on $S$, which we know it isn't.

Comment: Submanifolds with this property are called [*totally geodesic submanifolds*](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Totally_geodesic_submanifold).

Comment: You should clarify that in your question you are **assuming** that $M$ is totally geodesic in $N$. Also: What did you try to solve the problem and where did you get stuck? You simply have to follow the definition.